# What does a blank window represent in the list of apps displayed by double-clicking "home"?

Tags: ios

When I have "Pokemon Go" running, and I double-click the "home" button, I sometimes see a blank window in the list of apps that can be scrolled through by swiping to the right. I've *only* seen this happen with "Pokemon Go." And, the app functions just fine with, or without it.

What does that blank window represent?

[image]

btw: double-clicking "home" not only shows *running* apps, but also *recently run* apps, right?  Yet, I've never seen "Pokemon Go" in the list other than when it is explicitly running (never as a *recently run* app). So, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Is the blank window 'in place of' or 'in addition to' Pokemon Go?

Comment: @fsb In addition to. While the Pokemon Go app is running, it always is correctly displayed in the list of apps that are shown by double-clicking "home" . Then, sometimes, an extra window (that is blank) is displayed in that list. The only reason I know it is related to Pokemon Go is (1) killing, with a swipe-up, Pokemon Go also removes the blank window, (2) observation. I've had to re-start Pokemon Go so much, I started noticing that extra, blank, window, and Pokemon Go was always running at the same time.

Comment: What is the title of the blank window?  The title should be at the top when you're scrolling thru the apps.

Comment: @fsb I got lucky. It just happened again. I added a screen shot.

Comment: @fsb ok. I'll start paying attention to whether the issue is only with the "Settings" window.

Comment: By design, if the last time you used a window with private info, iOS will blank-out the screen when multitasking so that the data isn't viewable.

Comment: @fsb yes. yes. I see what is happening now. There was some selection bias that made me think it was a Pokemon Go issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer added from the comments)

Check the title of the window when you're in multitasking mode.  Some windows are either 'blanked' or 'blackened' in this mode to hide sensitive or proprietary info.

The window will refresh once it receives focus again.